ACTIVITI7 IN SpringBoot parse bpmn.20.xml error with multiInstanceLoopCharacteristics
I was trying to add a multiInstanceLoopCharacteristics element in bpmn.20.xml, after I add this element into the bpmn.20.xml file, the BaseBpmnXMLConverter can not get outgoings elements anymore.
A few times attempts, I found out that when I format the new bpmn.20.xml, the BaseBpmnXMLConverter can get the outgonings elements in right way, but it will failed if the bpmn.20.xml is in one row.
I try to format the xml and it work in the right way.
